# Do prime products naturally appear in any combinatorial problems?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For prime products, we mean a product such as: 2*3*5*7...*p or a subset of it.

Do such prime products naturally appear in any combinatorial problems ?

Ideally, can we find a combinatorial problem that is not directly related to prime numbers, but prime products "naturally" occurs in the answers of the problem ?

The reason we ask this question is that, factorial n! naturally appear in many combinatorial problems. We just want to see if we can find prime products in any interesting combinatorial problems.

Comment: Just to be clear, is $95=5\times 19$ a "prime product"? It is indeed a "subset" of the product of all prime numbers smaller or equal to $19$.

Answer (score 1):

Your prime products are the square-free numbers. These are also precisely the numbers for which the [Möbius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function) is non-zero. The Möbius function again occurs most prominently in the [Möbius inversion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_inversion_formula).